# MVC Querying a list of rights for logged on user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

The following ActionResult logs in a user and puts it in a cookie. I create a JSON string for the user data; which includes loggingOnUser.MergedRights (a list of type RightModel).

How can I access the merged rights list from a view to see if the user has a specific right?

**UserController**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = model.Email;
            string password = model.Password;

            var loggingOnUser = _userService.Login(username, password);

            if (loggingOnUser != null)
            {
                string userData = OptionBox.Common.JSON.ToJSON(loggingOnUser);

                var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, loggingOnUser.Email.ToString(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), true, userData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                //Encrypt ticket
                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

                //Create the cookie
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                }
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password provided is incorrect");
        return View(model);
    }
```

**RightModel.cs**

```
public class RightModel
{
    public string RightName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

**LoginModel.cs**

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RightModel> MergedRights { get; set; }
}
```

**Screenshot of userData as JSON**

[image: Screenshof of userData in JSON format]

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the obvious concerns that you shouldn't be creating cookies with sensitive data in plain text such as the username and password, the only way you can access data and perform operations on it in a view is if the data is already stored in a container accessible by the view, such as the ViewBag/ViewData, the Model or the TempData object.

In order to include the desired information within the view, you should read the data from the cookie in the controller, and then include it in either the ViewBag/TempData or the Model if that is applicable to your design, then you would simply access it as `ViewBag.MergedRigts` / `Model.MergedRights`, etc.

IMO these types of operations (checking for user permissions and authentication) should be done in a controller action instead of within a view, so that you can route the request to the respective view depending on the model and session data, but as far as simply accessing the data stored in a cookie, that's one way you can do it.

Comment: Ummm... he's using an encrypted forms authentication ticket, not plain text

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you're essentially bypassing all the built-in security that .NET provides for you, and that security is well written and extensive.  By bypassing, you're are fighting against the current.

What you need to do is implement a custom IPrincipal interface that can provide an IsMemberOf() implementation.  This way, you can use all the built-in security seamlessly.

I suggest you begin by reading up on IPrincipal, IIdentity, and custom implementations in MVC.